# What do you call a 'view' for music?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I'm building a platform where people can store and manage their physical music collection, like vinyl records, cd's and so on (it's called www.melodystack.com for whoever might be interested, it's not finished yet though).

People can keep track of how many times they played their albums (like here: https://gyazo.com/f62fa72b50f7d7eae229cf878b4bf7d9).

However, I tried to find the right word for this, like "views" with Youtube videos. As English not being  my primary language, I couldn't find the right word. I used "turn", but everybody who uses the system asks me "What does turn mean/do?" and when I ask them for a better word they don't know either. What would be a better word to use rather than "turn"?

Comment: I would use "listens" or "plays", ie if someone has listened to a track/album 20 times you could say there are "20 plays" or "20 listens" for that track/album.

Comment: @MaxWilliams That doesn't sound bad, thanks. However, is it legit to say "add listen" or "add play" for an album?

Comment: You could say "Log playing this" but if that's too long then "Add play" or "Add a play" would probably be clear enough.

Comment: @Derp, yes: "play" or "listen" can become nouns (or possibly pronouns) in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes calls them **Plays** and so do I.